# Show warning on missing column on VSSDT

Tags: sql-server-data-tools, ssdt-2019

On Visual Studio 2019 SSDT. Inside a procedure we have:

```
create table a (test1 varchar(50))
create table #b (test2 varchar(50))

select a.nop from a

select a.nop from a, #b b where a.test1 = b.test2
```

The first select gives a warning of columns missing, but the second one doesn't.
Is any configuration available to force a warning (or error) on the second select? The moment a temp table is present visual allows anything, even when the missing field has the "a."

Comment: Are you sure that you want to create a table "a" inside of a stored procedure as opposed to a temp table?  That's pretty unusual behavior for a proc.  After that, my guess would be missing schema reference like "dbo.a", but usually permanent tables are created outside of stored procedures.

Comment: The table inside the procedure was for the example. The tables would be created on the model but the second select would still not show a warning or error even when there's no "nop" field on table a.

Comment: Yes, I was able to reproduce it. Sometimes SSDT fails to resolve which table or subquery a column belongs to in big statements but this one is trivial. If you replace `#b` with any (even missing) normal table name then the warning appears. Once you replace the second table name with `#` or `@` the warning disappears. Feels like a bug or feature limitation. I'll report it next week if it's not already [there](https://github.com/microsoft/DacFx/issues)

Comment: Bug report https://github.com/microsoft/DacFx/issues/389